# subprocess.check_output with error exit code end the program

Tags: python, solaris

I'm at a very basic level in python, and I have this problem.

The command executed in a solaris environment

```
exec_ldap = subprocess.check_output(
    ["/usr/bin/ldapsearch", "-T", "-t", "-h", ldapserver, "-p", ldapport, "-b", path_ldap, "objectClass=*", "certificaterevocationlist"],
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

it has returned non-zero exit status 81, because the connection to the ldap server go to timeout.

But despite I catch this exception printing the output to a log file, the python script end, but i don't know why ?

I need that the program continue although the execution of the command go in timeout.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the code where you catch the exception?

Comment: You'll have to show us what you do and how. Only then we can help you. No prosa, just code.

Comment: >try:
>-exec_ldap_q = subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/ldapsearch", "-", "-t", "-h", ldapserver, "-p", ldapport, "-b", path_ldap,"objectClass=*","certificaterevocationlist"],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
>-except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
>*logger.error("errore di connessione con il server ldap "+str(e))